# How to show values in ggplot instead of geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
cluster <- c(rep(c(1:4), 2))
score <- c(1.3, 7.2, 4.9, 7.5, 6.8, 4.1, 9.9, 5.8)
x_axis <- c(rep("indicator1", 4), rep("indicator2", 4))

dt <- data.table(cluster, score, x_axis)
```

and I am plotting the score for each indicator by cluster:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dt, aes(x=x_axis, y=score))
```

I would like to do one of the following:

1. Replace the dots in the plot with cluster number (or put the number next to the dot), or
2. Use different shapes/color for each cluster and add a legend below the plot, indicating to which cluster does each shape correspond to.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's both options. To use shape for the clusters, pass `factor(cluster)` to the `shape` aesthetic of `geom_point`.

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(x_axis, score)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(cluster)), size = 4) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  labs(shape = 'Cluster')
```

[image]

If you just want labels at each point, you don't need the shape aesthetic, but you might want to draw in some white circles behind your text:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(x_axis, score)) +
  geom_point(size = 8, shape = 21, fill = 'white') +
  geom_text(aes(label = cluster), size = 5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

If you're writing to a format where colors are permissable, I think the clearest way to label the clusters would be to map them to the `color` aesthetic:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(x_axis, score)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cluster)), size = 8) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(color = 'Cluster')
```

[image]

Comment: any way to use both different colors and shapes? If I use `geom_point(aes(shape=factor(cluster), color=factor(cluster)))` it works, but they both show up in the legend